# Browser doesn't connect to the django web server

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use django, a python framework but my browser doesn't connect to the web server with the ip address provided. After I run the code 'python manage.py runserver' browser should open up with some congratulations! page but it keeps telling me can't reach the site[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqrLl.png)

Comment: Are you going to `127.0.0.1`? What does `python manage.py runserver` output? Does it give you a URL where it is running or does it give you an error?

Comment: Put on some screenshot of the python manage.py runserver output, that way we can help you, like this we're just blindly guessing the mistake.

Comment: Please include the output after you giver it the runserver command. So many things could be the reason for this. Reading the error is first stepping stone to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon running that command you should get a similar output to this:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 09, 2020 - 14:22:47
Django version 2.1.10, using settings 'django_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Anything beyond that means that your instance has crashed and there should be an error of some kind. Please update your question with that error if that's the case.
You could also access your local server with http://localhost:8000/.
I hope you are trying to access the URL from the same machine that is running the server.

If so, you may need to check antivirus or firewall and disable them individually temporarily to find the culprit.